# "Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade" while trying to upgrade to LTS 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

When I do `sudo do-release-upgrade` to update to the next LTS,
I get

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
```

The cause seems to be this (from `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`):

```
WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'
```

How do I resolve this problem? `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` displays too many broken packages, and I am lost on how to proceed. I know I should not delete `ubuntu-desktop`, what should I do?

Note, I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.
Nothing reports broken packages other than `do-release-upgrade`. I do not think I have broken package in current version, it seems more like upgrading would cause some broken links.

Comment: You should fix the broken packages and make sure your system is fully updated before attempting an upgrade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: You will have to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`  ,,, and fix any problems occurring here, among them the 'held broken packages.'

Comment: @ChanganAuto My system is fully updated, and I do not think there are broken packages when I am remaining in focal.

Comment: @SorenA Ofc I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before dist-upgrade. Does not affect

Comment: @ArturMeinild Ugh, that one is about broken packages while installing. This one happens when (and only when) I do `do-release-upgrade`, specifically with `ubuntu-desktop` package.

Comment: Something that you currently have installed is incompatible with 22.04. It's unlikely to be anything from the Ubuntu repositories. It's likely to be something you installed from some non-Ubuntu source or PPA. Review your apt sources, recall why you added those non-Ubuntu sources, uninstall that non-Ubuntu software, and disable those non-Ubuntu sources. Once you have uninstalled the conflicting packages, the release-upgrade will work. After the release-upgrade, you can *try* to reinstall the conflicting software, though is it also likely you will need to seek a compatible alternative.

Comment: Also see /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log for clues on what might be 'broken'.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, I am in great pain as `ppa-purge` was not able to detect my packages. ..Do I need to uninstall steam?   Also I do not recall which packages vulkan has installed.

Comment: @Abastro Were you able to fix this?