# cant' upgrade from ubuntu 20.04 --> 22.04 - 'Broken packages after upgrade: libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 for the past few hours, but no luck.
Here is the error message showing up in my `main.log` file:

```
2023-07-18 12:56:00,963 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2023-07-18 12:56:01,261 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
2023-07-18 12:56:01,497 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'
2023-07-18 12:56:01,513 DEBUG abort called
```

I already ran all of the `ppa-purge` things, and now the only `ubuntu-desktop` issue seems to persist. I tried to remove ubuntu-desktop, then reinstall ubuntu-desktop, then I removed `colord` and `mesa-utils`, but none of those things worked. I am still getting the same errors. So I am not sure what else to try. I also tried rebooting after these changes, and still no success.

I did also look at the `apt.log` and I am seeing these messages. But I am not really sure
how to interpret the errors. When I read this, it seems like the system is stuck in some loop where it cannot find the right dependencies to resolve the issue. But not sure how to fix this. Here is the log info.

```
Investigating (9) ubuntu-desktop:amd64 < 1.450.2 -> 1.481.1 @ii pumU Ib >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 < none | 43-2ubuntu1 @un umH >
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 2 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng:amd64 2 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 < 1.450.2 | 1.481.1 @ii umR >
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
  Considering ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 10000 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
Investigating (9) libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 < 1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1 -> 1.72.0-1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 Breaks on libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 | 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1.68.4-1+b1)
  Considering libgjs0g:amd64 17 as a solution to libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 279
  Upgrading libgjs0g:amd64 due to Breaks field in libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64
Investigating (9) libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 -> 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Depends on libmozjs-91-0:amd64 < none | 91.10.0-0ubuntu1 @un umH > (>= 91.10.0)
  Considering libmozjs-91-0:amd64 2 as a solution to libgjs0g:amd64 17
  MarkKeep libgjs0g:amd64 < 1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01 -> 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back libgjs0g:amd64 rather than change libmozjs-91-0:amd64
Done
```

Note that I looked at the following posts:

["Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade" while trying to upgrade to LTS 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428922/cant-mark-ubuntu-desktop-for-upgrade-while-trying-to-upgrade-to-lts-22-04)

[Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

[Ubuntu 20.04.1 upgrade failure / ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: colord'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281969/ubuntu-20-04-1-upgrade-failure-error-dist-upgrade-failed-broken-packages-aft)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2481783&page=2

[Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failing due to "broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262109/upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04-failing-due-to-broken-packages-after-upgrade-ubunt)

[Can't seem to upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 due to held back packages: libsensors4, libsensors-config, colord](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230374/cant-seem-to-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-due-to-held-back-packages-libsensors4/1242078#1242078)

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue, https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/2009754 helped me to fix it; namely [Vitaliy Komarov's](https://launchpad.net/%7Emkots) steps here:

1. `apt remove colord mesa-utils`, and then `do-release-upgrade` started working.
2. After upgrading was finished, I installed deleted packages again and everything seems OK: `apt install gnome-control-center ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I just ended up reformatting my OS drive, and building 22.04 from USB. But thanks for the suggestions.